# how to write a xpath for list box with below html code (for selenium use - with salesforce)

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, salesforce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8DGa.png)

I tried the xpath as "`//div[label[contains(., 'Completion Status')]]/a`" - this is not working as there is few number of /Div
This is for salesforce selenium automation .

other objects like PO number works fine with the code as below :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[label[contains(., 'If PO number cannot be given by customer fill in this field with')]]/input")).sendKeys("9845");`

Comment: Paste this html code into the question. You can use the tool as https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html to format it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Completion Status')]"/../..//a))
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the HTML I think the below xpath may work for you :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Completion Status')]/../following-sibling::div[@class='uiMenu']/descendant::a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Completion Status')]/../../div[@class='uiMenu']//a"))
```